# Nestjs. TypeError: root path must be a string

Tags: typescript, express, nestjs

I am configuring the static files folder in `main.ts`

```
  app.useStaticAssets({
    root: path.resolve(__dirname + '/public'),
  });
```

Now on runtime am having an error `TypeError: root path must be a string`
I tried to use `path.join(__dirname + '/public'),` - didn't help.

I do import path like `import * as path from 'path'`

Any ideas how to fix?

**UPDATE**:
as per answers above I am trying:

`app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'public'));` - getting an error `{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Cannot GET /"}`

also tried:

```
app.useStaticAssets({
    root: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public'),
    prefix: '/public/',
  });
```

Still getting same error with this one - `TypeError: root path must be a string`

My controller method looks like:

```
  @Get()
  root(@Res() res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html');
  }
```

**UPDATE**:
If I have `app.useStaticAssets(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public'));` and removing `root` controller method still having `404` error.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the configuration is different for express and fastify:

### Express (default)

```
app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'public'));
```

### Fastify

```
app.useStaticAssets({      
    root: join(__dirname, '..', public'),
    prefix: '/public/',
});
```

---

`join` is directly imported in the examples.

```
import { join } from 'path';
```

---

If you are serving static content you don't need to add a specific controller; the assets will automatically be available via the middleware.

Lets assume you have two files under `/public`: `index.html` and `image.png`

- `localhost:3000` and `localhost:3000/index.html` serve `index.html`
- `localhost:3000/image.png` serves `image.png`

See this simple [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/54x0w1y38l) without a controller.

Comment: Hi I just used ``app.useStaticAssets(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public'));``  saying `{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Cannot GET /"}`

Comment: Can you show the code of your controller? Have you added `@Render`?

Comment: I have edited my answer: Just remove your controller method `root` and go to `localhost:3000`.

Comment: Interesting but that didn't help. After I remove the controller method `root` still getting `{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Cannot GET /"}` using `app.useStaticAssets(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public'));`

Comment: Are you using express or fastify?

Comment: I am using the default - express.

Comment: Have a look at this simple example without any controller. It just serves all the files in `/public`: https://codesandbox.io/s/54x0w1y38l

Comment: Not yet, I'll let you know

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the `prefix` property.

## Fix

```
  app.useStaticAssets({
    root: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public'),
    prefix: '/public/',
  });
```

## More

- Docs: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mvc
- Relevant issue : https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1083

Comment: still having an issue

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth to anyone; I spent a while on this then realised that my `await app.listen(3000);` was before my `app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'public'));`.